# UnicodeDecodeError On Unicode File Read

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, unicode, cgi

I have a problem where, when I execute a script which involved reading in data from a file that contains unicode code points, everything works fine. But when it is executed via another application, it is raising the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

I am executing the exact same code using the exact same data file. A sample datafile that replicates the problem is like this:

```
¥ Α © §
```

I called this `sample.txt`

A very simple python script to simply read in and print the file contents:

```
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)

print("Done")
```

This executes fine from the command line; executing via Apache/CGI fails with the above error.

Answer (score 1):

A hint to the problem came from the documentation of the `open` function:

> In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is
>   platform dependent: locale.getpreferredencoding(False) is called to
>   get the current locale encoding.
>   [[Link]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Platform dependent suggested environment variables. So, I inspected what environment variables were set for my shell, and found `LANG` set to `en_US.UTF-8`. Dumping the environment variables set by Apache found that `LANG` was missing.

So, apparently when locale cannot be determined, Python uses ASCII as the default file encoding. As a result, the error was encountered when the ordinal was out of range for ASCII.

To fix this, I set this environment variable in my CGI script. If the environment variable is somehow missing from a user shell, it can be set via normal methods, or just by:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Or whatever preferred encoding is desired.

Note, the issue is probably far more noticeable if the locale is missing from a user shell, as text editors like vi will not display characters without it. It was significantly more subtle when only an issue when called from Apache (or some other application).